# Find versions of SAP Hybris's dependencies

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm working with Hybris 1810. I want to know the version of Spring, JUnit, Mockito. Where can I find them?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the libraries are in the `core` extension: `hybris/bin/platform/ext/core/lib`.

You can also use `find` command to find them:

```
find <hyrbis-dir> -name "spring*.jar"
find <hyrbis-dir> -name "junit*.jar"
find <hyrbis-dir> -name "mockito*.jar"
```